# DockPanel doesn't change sizes when i'm cliking MaximizeButton

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I create user interface in WPF. I have one problem with menu i used DockPanel for it, all works good but there is one problem when i click MaximizeButton DockPanel size don't change like in this pic.
http://xmages.net/i/3405572

Code:

```
   <Grid >
    <DockPanel Background="LightBlue">
        <Menu Height="23"  Name="menu1"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"> 
            <MenuItem Header="File" Name="File_Menu"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Tasks" Name="Tasks_Menu"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="View" Name="View_Menu"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="HandBook" Name="HandBook_Menu"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Email" Name="Email_Menu"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Tools" Name="Tools_Menu"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Options" Name="Options_Menu"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Help" Name="Help_Menu"></MenuItem>
        </Menu>
     .........
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine its due to the container of the DockPanel the grid, or the way the Dockpanel is set in this grid.